# C++: Sorting name/age pairs alphabetically, can only manage 5 pairs

Tags: c++

Sorry if this post isn't the best, I'm brand new to the site and coding in general. My programs take input like "Sam 16 Emily 4 Molly 19" and sorts it alphabetically, while keeping the ages the same. It works like a charm, unless you enter more than 5 pairs. After you enter 5, the following names are sorted fine, but the ages aren't the right ones. I'm not sure where the code is getting the numbers it's outputting. This is my code. I apologize for posting everything (~30 lines), but I really don't know where the issue is.

```
#include"../std_lib_facilities.h"


vector<string> name;
vector<int> age;

void read_pairs()
{
    string n;
    int v;

    while (cin >> n >> v && n != "NoName") {    // read string int pair
        for (int i = 0; i<name.size(); ++i)
        name.push_back(n);
        age.push_back(v);
    }
}

void write_pairs(string label)
{
    cout << label;
    for (int i = 0; i<name.size(); ++i)
        cout << '(' << name[i] << ',' << age[i] << ")\n";
}

int find_index(const vector<string>& v, const string& n)
// find n's index in v
{
    for (int i = 0; i<n.size(); ++i)
    if (n == v[i]) return i;
}

int main()
try
{
    cout << "Please enter your name/age pairs. When finished, enter 'No More'\n";
    read_pairs();


    vector<string> original_names = name;   // copy the names
    vector<int> original_ages = age;        // copy the ages

    sort(name.begin(), name.end());         // sort the names

    for (int i = 0; i<name.size(); ++i)     // update ages
        age[i] = original_ages[find_index(original_names, name[i])];

    write_pairs("\nSorted:\n");

    keep_window_open("~");  
}
catch (runtime_error e) {   
    cout << e.what() << '\n';
    keep_window_open("~");  
}
catch (...) {   
    cout << "exiting\n";
    keep_window_open("~");  
}
```

Comment: I think your problem has to do with the way vectors assign by reference.  Will post answer shortly.

Comment: This can't possibly work - `name` vector is always empty, because of this loop: `for (int i = 0; i<name.size(); ++i) name.push_back(n);` At the beginning, `name.size() == 0`, so the loop's body never runs and `push_back` never happens.

Comment: @hosch250: I'm not quite sure what you're thinking but `std::vector` doesn't "assign by reference".

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Does this explain why it can only properly handle 5 pairs? The way you worded it, it sounds like it shouldn't work at all, but it does.

Comment: @Blastfurnace No, I found that out as I was testing it.  I use C# mainly now, so I forgot.  I have the problem solved, though.

Comment: @Nickless: That `for` loop inside the `while` loop serves no purpose. Once you've read a name and age just `push_back` each to their respective containers. Your next problem is that sorting the `name` container doesn't automatically sort the `age` container. You might want both fields to be members of a `struct` or `class` so they can be treated as a single object.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Thanks! I was actually playing around with a struct, but without much luck. I'll report back if I manage it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many problems in your code.  I couldn't even get it to compile for a while.

In the first place, that `for` loop in `read_pairs()` is preventing you from storing any names in `name`.  In the second place, you need to see if `n` in `read_pairs()` is the break signal **before** inputting the age - otherwise you will break `cin`, you will learn that later, as I know that you are using Bjarne Stroustrup's book - the same one I learned from.  In the third place, your code was breaking in `find_index()` because you were calling `i < n.size();` rather than `i < v.size();` in your `for` loop.  Finally, you may want to handle multiple instances of the same name so you don't get one age for it.  I have implemented a simple way to do this by setting the value of `v[i]` to `""` in `find_index()` before I returned the position of the name in the array - this way, you cannot get the age for that name more than once.

This is the working code, with some comments included.  Feel free to ask if you don't understand something, but I think you understand enough to figure it out.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include"../std_lib_facilities.h"

vector<string> name;
vector<int> age;

void read_pairs()
{
  string n;
  int v;

  while (true) {  // read string int pair

    cin >> n;   // input name

    if (n == "No")  // if name is "No", break so we do not input a string for age
      break;

    cin >> v;   // input age

    // insert name/age into vectors
    name.push_back(n);
    age.push_back(v);
  }
}

void write_pairs(string label)
{
  cout << label;
  for (int i = 0; i<name.size(); ++i)
    cout << '(' << name[i] << ',' << age[i] << ")\n";   // output name/age pairs
}

int find_index(vector<string>& v, const string n)
// find n's index in v
{
  for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
  {
    if (n == v[i])
    {
      v[i] = "";  // remove name in case two of same name
      return i;
    }
  }
}

int main()
try
{
  cout << "Please enter your name/age pairs. When finished, enter 'No More'\n";

  read_pairs(); // read name/age pairs

  vector<string> original_names = name;   // copy the names
  vector<int> original_ages = age;    // copy the ages

  sort(name.begin(), name.end());     // sort the names

  for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++)   // update ages
    age[i] = original_ages[find_index(original_names, name[i])];

  write_pairs("\nSorted:\n");   // write name/age pair

  keep_window_open("~");
}
catch (runtime_error e) {
  cout << e.what() << '\n';
  keep_window_open("~");
}
catch (...) {
  cout << "exiting\n";
  keep_window_open("~");
}
```

Comment: This is absolutely wonderful, thank you! It makes way more sense than what I was attempting on my end. I don't seem to be able to up vote this, but I am hugging you in spirit.